# Does CC0 1.0 Universal require attribution?

Tags: licensing, creative-commons

I would like to use photos from the [Public Domain Archive](http://publicdomainarchive.com/) without attribution. They say that their photos are free for personal and commerical use. But they don't mention whether or not they need attribution. They are licensed under the [cc0](https://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/). Do I need to attribute them for the use of one of their photos?

Answer (score 1):

No. CC0 (and its equivalents) is the closest "moral equivalent" to public domain; it says, essentially, that the work is licensed for all uses with no restrictions or qualifications, other than that the author of the work still holds copyright in those jurisdictions where voluntary alienation (release into the public domain) is legally impossible. Attribution is nice, sometimes, but not necessary.

(And there are times when the author of the work would just as soon nobody mentioned them because the work is "off brand" - it doesn't fit into their normal style or genre, and it would just confuse their market.)

Answer (score 0):

This is a legal question and the best answer to your question would be to consult with a legal professional licensed in your jurisdiction. All that being said, and understanding that we can't provide legal advice, CC0 means the creator has provided it to the public domain, without any copyright assertion, for **any** and **all** use. That suggests that attribution is not required. But again, consult with a legal professional for actual legal advice.